# how to write two way dataBind in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

please help me how to use two way dataBind
Here when i add [(ngModel)="Hello"]  its through an Errro

```
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)="Jan"]/><br />
       <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)="feb"] /><br />
  {{Jan}}  {{feb}}
```

**typescript**

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
 <input type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Jan">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)="feb">
```

Comment: Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("input type="text" class="form-control" /><br />-->
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="Jan">{{Jan}}

Comment: @MdNajju make sure you've imported FormsModule into the module that's hosting the component.